# Make a variable const in cpp then give its address to a pointer but dereferencing not mutate the variable why?

Tags: c++

making a variable  const in cpp then give its address to a pointer  and change its value by dereferecing but I still gets the value that I stored initially.

code snippet

```
const int a = 5;
    // then
    // a = 7; not possible
    // bypassing const using pointers
    int *ap = (int *)&a;
    *ap = 10;

    cout << *ap <<" "<< *(&a)<<" " << a << endl;
```

Output is:

10 10 5

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior, by attempting to mutate a constant object.

Comment: Because of the undefined behavior anything can happen.

Answer (score 5):

Any program that modifies a variable or member declared `const` has behaviour no longer defined by the C++ standard.

This is known as UB.  Common symptoms of UB are crashing, "it seems to work", wierd inconsistent state, and even time travel where the future UB changes behaviour *before* it happens in your code.

A good C++ programmer engages in habits that make UB very unlikely.

The symptom of UB you are seeing here is that because there is no program whose behaviour is specified by the C++ standard `const int x=5;` can have any value except `5`, the compiler replaces reads to `x` with the constant `5`.

On the other hand, you can form a pointer to `x`, and `x` does have bytes there.  The compiler is free to put `x` in ROM or  a protected page, or it could just not bother and put it in normal memory.

You form a pointer to `x`.  The compiler doesn't elide away this pointer (it is allowed to, but also allowed not to) so in your machine code it actually reads and writes to the data at the address where `x` is stored.  Thus `*&x` is `10` while `x` is `5`.  What more, `*&x` could be `5` if the compiler optimizes the pointer away.

Avoid UB.

C++ defines an abstract machine, and the C++ program has behaviour defined on it (unless you do UB).  This is then translated into machine code that is guaranteed consistent with the abstract machine behaviour, but there is no guarantee at all that C++ code that naively looks like it "should" map to certain machine code does.

That gap - between abstract and concrete - permits a lot of optimization.

C++ abstract machine behaviour is designed to *easily* map to machine code, and UB is left in where enforcing certain behaviour would have costs.

Answer (score 0):

It is already pefectly answered - modification of const is undefined behavior and it does not make sense trying to decipher undefined behavior as it is dependend on the inner desing of a compiler and not on any standard.

However there is a standard way of how to bypass const: using [const_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) keyword. It can be used for example if input parameter of some function does not expect a constant but your input is constant. Nevertheless modification even after casting away constness still lead to an undefined behavior!

Comment: `const_cast` is also undefined here. The `(int *)` is *defined to be* a `const_cast` in this situation